# Operator % is undefined when trying to define a predicate for my extension method

Tags: dart

I want to learn how to extend `List` class with the following trivial `Filter`. However, it does not compile

```
extension on List {
  void Filter<T>({bool Function(T)? predicate}) {
    this.forEach((element) {
      if (predicate?.call(element) ?? false) {
        print(element);
      }
    });
  }
}

void main() {
  List.generate(10, (x) => x * x).Filter(predicate: (y) => y % 3 == 0);
}
```

with the following errors:

```
dart/delegate.dart:12:62: Error: The operator '%' isn't defined for the class 'Object?'.
 - 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
Try correcting the operator to an existing operator, or defining a '%' operator.
  List.generate(10, (x) => x * x).Filter(predicate: (y) => y % 3 == 0);
                                                             ^
```

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the extension is declared on `List`, aka. `List<Object?>`.
That means you don't know anything about the type of the elements.

You may instead want to make the extension on a `List<T>` and capture the `T`.

```dart
extension FilterListExtension<T> on List<T> {
  void filter({bool Function(T)? predicate}) {
    for (var element in this) {
      if (predicate?.call(element) ?? false) {
        print(element);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can create list of `int`s and use it as one:

```dart
 [for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) i * i].filter(predicate((y) => y % 3 == 0));
```

It's important that the *static* type of the list matches the parameter of the filter predicate. For `List.generate(10, (x) => x * x)`, you create a `List<Object?>`, and you should instead write `List<int>.generate(10, (x) => x * x)`, or use the literal form above.

Answer (score 0):

check this out:

```dart
extension on List {
  void filter<T extends num>({bool Function(T)? predicate}) {
    this.forEach((element) {
      if (predicate?.call(element) ?? false) {
        print(element);
      }
    });
  }
}

void main() {
  List.generate(10, (x) => x * x).filter<num>(predicate: (y) => y % 3 == 0);
}
```